# XGBoost only predcinting single class for the unseen data out of 18 classes for Multiclass Text Classification problem

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost, text-classification

In the current situation, the XGBoost model that I have trained is only producing a single class for the unseen dataset though the accuracy that I have received on then validation set is around 64% which is not bad for my use case.

In my current use case, I am trying to predict a target class for each text written and these are 18 odd classes and the total data set size is just over a 1000 rows (very small) but my primary question is that why XGB is only producing a single class.

I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
 #tf-idf verctor representation
 tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word',
                     stop_words=stopwords_custom,
                     max_features=total_features,
                     lowercase=True)
 fitted_vectorizer = tfidf_vect.fit(X_train)
 xtrain_tfidf = fitted_vectorizer.transform(X_train)
 xval_tfidf = fitted_vectorizer.transform(X_val)
 #Running the XGB model
 xgb_params = {"max_depth": (3,5,7),'n_estimators': (50,100,150),
'reg_alpha':[0.1,0.5,1],'reg_lambda':[1,1.5,2],'min_child_weight':[2,4,6]}
 from xgboost import XGBClassifier
 xgb_clf = XGBClassifier()
 grid_xgb = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_clf,
                    param_grid=xgb_params,
                    cv=5,
                    n_jobs=-1)
 grid_xgb.fit(xtrain_tfidf,y_train)

 print(grid_xgb.best_params_)
 print(grid_xgb.best_score_)
 #Training the model with best params
 final_xgb = XGBClassifier(max_depth = 5,
                      reg_alpha = 1,
                      reg_lambda = 1,
                      n_estimators = 100,
                      objective='multi:softmax',num_class=18,
                      random_state=42)
 final_xgb.fit(xtrain_tfidf,y_train)
 final_xgb_predict = final_xgb.predict(xval_tfidf)
 xgb_accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(final_xgb_predict, y_val)
 print ("XGBoost > Accuracy: ", xgb_accuracy)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where am I going wrong?

TLDR: you are training/making predictions using sparse data matrices, but you should be using dense data matrices. Convert your `fitted_vectorizer.transform(X)` results to dense using `<ndarray>.todense()` method, and see if the situation improves.

XGBoost interprets an empty cell as a missing value, rather than a 0 count.

If you replace `XGBClassifier` with some Scikit-Learn classifier (eg. `GradientBoostingClassifier`) then your existing code would work as expected. The reason being that Scikit-Learn interprets empty cells differently, as 0 counts.

Comment: The other classifiers are working well on the training data but their overall accuracy is comparatively lower to XGBoost and that's the sole reason I wanted to use XGBoost. But your point is taken. I am checking the change in the output after converting the sparse matrix to a dense matrix.

Comment: What impact will the model have if I convert my fitted_vectorizer.tranfrom(X) to fitted_vectorizer.tranfrom(X).toarray() instead of fitted_vectorizer.tranfrom(X).todense() ?

Comment: You must train the XGBoost model with dense TF-IDF data matrix, and must make predictions in the exact same configuration. You can't do it partially - train with sparse, and then predict with dense (or vice versa).

Comment: More details about combining TF(-IDF) and XGBoost can be found here: https://openscoring.io/blog/2021/02/27/sklearn_tf_tfidf_xgboost_pipeline/